# Is it advisable to save an ML model as a Joblib/Pickle file?

Tags: python, classification, pandas, random-forest, numpy

Part of our thesis project is to create a Diabetes predictor web application, and I have something I like to clarify. Is it a common practice to save an ML model as a Joblib/Pickle file like this one? I've seen a lot of notebooks on Kaggle regarding Diabetes prediction, and I rarely see anyone saving the ML model as a Joblib/Pickle file. Thanks for the help!

[image: Saving ML model as a joblib file]

Answer (score 2):

[Scikit Learn Documentation: 9. Model Persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html)

Using `joblib` is the recommended way in the documentation. However keep the limitations that are mentioned there in mind.

As for whether this is advisable: If you want to use your model in real-world application and it takes a long time to train, training the model from scratch every time will take you a long time. Training and saving it, then subsequently loading it when you need it is faster. If you want to share your trained model, problems with compatibility may arise. In that case it could be better to re-train the model on the new machine and save it there instead of sharing it and causing problems.

Comment: Thanks! May I know if Joblib is actually used in the industry, or in a real-world data science setup? If not, may I know what kind of advanced tools data scientists use in scenarios similar to this?

Comment: There are other ways, like [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`dill`](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) or Neural Networks are often stored as hdf-files. For scikit-learn `joblib` is the officially recommended way to go that finds widespread use as far as I can tell. As long as you stick to the recommendations by whatever library you're using and document the steps it took you to create your model such that it is reproducible, you'll be fine.

Comment: joblib is very common irl